# How to add multiple query WHERE statements that may or may not have a value

Tags: mysql, forms, search

I'm creating a form that allows the user to search a database for different criteria: location, city, min price, max price, etc.

I have a "base" select statement: `SELECT * FROM table`.

In the search form there are several text boxes and dropdowns that may or may not have values, depending on what the user wants to search by.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to add WHERE clauses to the sql statement when there may or may not be a value to use for a particular table column (based on the user's selection).

Thanks for anyone's help!

Comment: can you show some code? what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by `may or may not`. Use select *.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code where you generate the SQL, check what fields the user has entered and append more checks to the query as you find more input from the user. Quick example in PHP:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$where_checks = array();

if (isset($_POST['city']))
   $where_checks[] = "city = '{$_POST['city']}'";
if (isset($_POST['location']))
   $where_checks[] = "location = '{$_POST['location']}'";

// Add more stuff here

if (count($where_checks) > 0)
   $sql .= " WHERE " . implode('AND', $where_checks);

// run query
```

I have intentionally left out sanitation / escaping of the post input to keep the example simple. But you obviously **must sanitize the input as well**.

Mind the extra space before the `WHERE` otherwise the query will be broken.

Comment: Makes sense, SilverSnake. And thanks for the reminder about cleaning the user's entries. Thanks!

Comment: @eventide Sure thing! And thanks to Lex for fixing my silly code mistake. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach

```
select 
    columns
from 
    table
where 
    (location=@location or @location is null) and
    (city=@city or @city is null) and
    .
    .
```